# Why does char* of an array point to the entire array instead of the address?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I've seen some similar questions asked on here, but haven't been able to find a concise answer.

In learning pointers, I've come to understand that
in a case of

`int test=1; int* p = &test;`
printing "p" with `printf("%p", p);` will give the address of test, while printing *p  with `printf("%d", *p);` will give the actual value of test, which is what ptr p points to.

Now, for doing this with a char, doing
`char word[] = "test"; char* ptr = &word[0];`
then printing ptr with `printf("%s", ptr);` gives the output "test", but I expected it to give the address of `word[0]`.

I have figured out that if I do `printf("%p", ptr);` it does print the address.

So my question is, does this pointer contain both the address and the value of the array `test[]`? Or does printf just grab what it needs based off of which of `%s` or `%p` you use, and in that case, why couldn't you just do `printf("%d",test);` in my earlier example and get the value of test rather than the address? Is the fact that I'm using %s automatically outputting the entire array since it starts at that address?

Comment: Pointers contain only address. The values are contained in the memory having this address. The format specifiers of the `printf` tell it what to do with the pointer - to print the address or the string it is pointing to.

Comment: Pointers always point to a single address.  The `%s` format specifier is saying to print the string which starts at that address, which is a null-terminated character array, so it will start with the first character and keep going until it finds that null-terminator character.

Comment: `printf("%p", p);` prints the value of `p`, not the address of `p`.  The latter would be `&p`.  The value of `p` is the address of `test` .

Comment: ah, yes sorry I miss typed. I've fixed it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` tells `printf` to take the pointer it is given and print the first character that is there, then the character after that, then the character after that, and so on until `printf` finds a null character (a character that has value zero).

So, this not about a pointer pointing to the “entire array.” The pointer just points to one thing. It is about the command given to `printf`. `%p` says “print the value of the pointer.” `%s` says “print the characters at the location pointed to.”

> … why couldn't you just do `printf("%d",test);` in my earlier example and get the value of test rather than the address?

`%d` is a command to `printf` to print the value of the `int` it is passed. You should not pass it a pointer for this because `printf` is expecting an `int`. That is just what the command is for.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense! When you say that %s takes the pointer it is given, does that mean when I just print my word array and don't involve pointers at all, C is passing a pointer I don't see to printf? If I were to do `printf("%s", word);`. Does the char array named "word" become a pointer in that situation? or can printf take either a pointer to the address or the actual array itself?

Comment: Whenever an array, such as `word`, is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element unless it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array. So, in `printf("%s", word);`, `word` becomes a pointer. It is the same as passing the address of the first element explicitly, as in `printf("%s", &word[0]);`.